# kendo chart baseunit second date format

Tags: jquery, charts, kendo-ui, date-format

Working on Kendo chart, I have noticed that if we set base unit of any axis to the "seconds", the labels will show only `01:00:00` format of the date. What I want to do is to change it dynamically.
I have found following for it in the `Kendo.all.min.js`

```
oa = {
   seconds: "HH:mm:ss",
   minutes: "HH:mm",
   hours: "HH:mm",
   days: "M/d",
   weeks: "M/d",
   months: "MMM 'yy",
   years: "yyyy"
},
```

Now if I set seconds to "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" from"HH:mm:ss", it works fine I can see both date and time on my axis, now my question is how can I set it dynamic using jquery? because its not always good to modify kendo's script.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.
We can set label format as following.

```
labels:{template: "#= formatToMonthYear(value) #"}

function formatToMonthYear(val){return kendo.toString(new Date(val), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');}
```

Thanks

Comment: Implemented dynamic also